# Operation not permitted when creating virtual environment at mounted drive

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

everyone!

I'm trying to initiate a new project and I'm struggling at creating the virtual environment.

I always initiate it with `virtualenv env`, but since I'm creating it inside a folder at a mounted drive (the HD where I keep other files) instead of in my main SSD, it returns me the following message:

`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/bin/python3' -> '/media/jmg/FILES/allhot/env/bin/python'`

I understand it has something to do with permissions within the mounted drive, but does anyone know how to solve it? My ssd is getting full and I think this project is going to consume a lot of data...

Comment: What FS is at the mounted drive? The host OS is Linux hence `virtualenv` creates environment using symlinks but does the mounted FS support symlinks? It it's FAT or NTFS it doesn't. To avoid symlinks use `virtualenv --always-copy env`

Comment: it is in fact FAT. I'll try your command! Thanks!

Comment: I was able to create the virtualenv and it brought all system libs with it to the env folder. Guess I'll have to format the drive in ext4 then...

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115564/wsl-ubuntu-distro-how-to-solve-operation-not-permitted-on-cloning-repository

using @rsteckler's answer to update the `/etc/wsl.conf` file.