# Error: Command '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Error: Command '['/Users/francesco/Documents/random/.venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Why and how do I solve this message when I install a virtual environment?

I tried both and I still get the message above.

```
python -m venv .venv
python3 -m venv .venv
```

I'm using python 3.9.2 64-bit on my VSC.

Answer (score 4):

I was using python 3.11 so I needed to

`apt install python3.11-venv`

Answer (score 2):

See these two

[Operation not permitted when creating virtual environment at mounted drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839344/operation-not-permitted-when-creating-virtual-environment-at-mounted-drive)

https://superuser.com/questions/1388019/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-1-operation-not-p.

I used this command running under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

```
sudo virtualenv --always-copy --python=python3 .venv
```

and it worked. However, I'm not sure this is the best approach because subsequent `pip install` type things still occasionally fail with permissions issues.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you got the message because the venv package is not present on your system.

Solve it by installing the venv package (for example on Ubuntu, commands go into the Terminal):

```
apt install python3-venv
```

Maybe pip needs to be installed, too:

```
apt install python3-pip
```

Then create a new venv virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv ~/.venvs/my-venv-name
```

The above assumes that inside your home directory, you have previously created a directory called `.venv`, inside of which the venv virtual environments will be stored. If not, it can be created with `mkdir ~/.venv`

---

***You might need to prepend `sudo` to the commands, depending on what privileges your user has, like so:***

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
sudo python3 -m venv ~/.venvs/my-venv-name
```